# Launching JupyterQ from Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, kdb

I'm following [Kx instructions on installing jupyterq, embedpy and kdb in Anaconda](https://code.kx.com/q/ml/setup/#download-via-anaconda). This is [where I want to get to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mig2j.png) - a Jupyter notebook where I enter q commands. However, when I launch Jupyter notebook from Anaconda Navigator, I'm only able to create a new Python 3 notebook.

How do I create a notebook which accepts *q* commands?

Checked so far:

- I can launch *q* from ubuntu terminal, it's licensed
- In Anaconda Navigator, base environment shows *jupyterq*, *embedpy* and *kdb* as installed
- I see *jupyterq_kernel.q* and others in my *~/anaconda/q* directory

EDIT: Meanwhile, I downloaded [Jupyter kernel for kdb+](https://github.com/kxsystems/jupyterq) manually. Its `install.sh` apparently registered *q* kernel for Jupyter. I'm able to open a notebook with `jupyter notebook` from terminal.

Comment: Hello @Xpector! I'm one of the Anaconda developers working with the Kx team to build these packages. We'll look into this ASAP, and I'll respond here.

Comment: We've identified the issue and will be uploading corrected and updated packages today.

Comment: @Michael, thanks, that was quick! Should I repeat `conda install -c kx jupyterq`?

Comment: Yes, that will work!

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The below is now redundant as the Conda package has been fixed, but is left for reference**

You can follow the guide here http://www.enlistq.com/installing-kdb-jupyterq-and-embedpy-using-conda/ in order to add the kernel to Jupyter, it seems the package misses kernel.json

From the comments it appears this is or will be fixed, but given you've already installed everything, it is likely quicker to follow the relevant section of this tutorial (under "installing jupyterq")

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But in fact, there is no longer a need to manually install the kernel.json file.